# can't install open-interpreter. Error for rustc

Tags: rust-cargo, openai-api, failed-installation

#### Describe the bug

I have tried to install open interpreter but I always get this error: [Click for error details](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1128589450692280490/1163185769335234570/image.png)
but then again, I try to install rustup-init.exe and I get this: [Click for  details](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1128589450692280490/1163186156645658744/image.png)

when I open rustup-init.exe it gives me this

```
"The Cargo home directory is located at:

  C:\Users\alifh\.cargo

This can be modified with the CARGO_HOME environment variable.

The cargo, rustc, rustup and other commands will be added to
Cargo's bin directory, located at:

  C:\Users\alifh\.cargo\bin
                                                                                                                        
The Cargo home directory is located at:

  C:\Users\alifh\.cargo

This can be modified with the CARGO_HOME environment variable.

The cargo, rustc, rustup and other commands will be added to
Cargo's bin directory, located at:

  C:\Users\alifh\.cargo\bin

This path will then be added to your PATH environment variable by
modifying the HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Environment/PATH registry key.

You can uninstall at any time with rustup self uninstall and
these changes will be reverted."
```

but if I try to find rust by manually going to C:\Users\alifh here .cargo folder doesn't exists. when I do echo $env:path it shows this path "C:\Users\alifh.cargo\bin" but when I check user or system path from environment variables I don't see "C:\Users\alifh.cargo\bin" this there. and no rustc --version or anything related to rust dosesn't work. including rustup self uninstall this command. So I can't even uninstall and install or reinstall it.

#### Reproduce

1. I type the command "pip install open-interpreter"
2. I get this error: [Click for error details](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1128589450692280490/1163185769335234570/image.png)
3. I try to install rust by opening rustup-init.exe but it just gives me a window directly saying where my cargo is located. but the cargo file isn't really there. I can't find it in C:\Users\alifh [Click for  details](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1128589450692280490/1163186156645658744/image.png)
4. Since I can't use rust commands in command prompt/powershell I don't know how to reinstall it since `rustup self uninstall`  command also don't get recognized.

#### Screenshots

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1128589450692280490/1163185769335234570/image.png
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1128589450692280490/1163186156645658744/image.png

#### Open Interpreter version

probably latest! since I only input "pip install open-interpreter"

#### Python version

Python 3.12.0

#### Operating System name and version

Windows 11

#### Additional context

I expected to use rustc --version and cargo --version to work in powershell. and then proceed to smoothly install open-interpreter.